# "Many books" vs. "many of books"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is it correct to say "Many of books are in English" or should we say "Many books are in English"?

Comment: The TL;DR answer is No you don't use OF unless using a pronoun (eg my, your, his)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please put more effort into your posts, it's rather tiring to edit each and every one of them for really basic punctuation. Also, note that many of your questions are simply too basic for this site. You might be interested in our proposed sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thanks and welcome again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *many* functions as a determiner, as here, it must be followed by a plural noun with no article, so it has to be *Many books . . .* It can also function as an indefinite pronoun, but, when it does, it occurs as *many of*, and the following noun must be preceded by the definite article (*Many of the books . . .*) or another deteminer.

Answer (score 1):

If the noun phrase following *many* or *most* begins with a word such as *this*, *these*, *those*, *my*/*mine, *your(*s), *her*(*s*), their*(s*), *his*, or our(s*), the preposition *of* is required to create a partitive construction. If the semantic referent and head of the following noun phrase is itself the first word, *of* is not permitted.

Incidentally, 'Please put more effort into your posts, it's rather tiring to edit each and every one of them for really basic punctuation' is a run-on, not a sentence.

Comment: Incidentally, a run-on *is* a sentence, by definition. Also, whether a comma splice is a run-on, is debatable. Lastly, answers are not expected to be getting off-topic fixing stylistic issues in comments, especially since commenters are under no obligation to follow a particular style guide in the first place.